# Al abrir carpeta en servidor se abre un archivo

Tags: php

[image: pasos]

Estoy siguiendo estas instrucciones pero al llegar al paso 4 si intento abrir localhost/booking o cualquier subcarpeta de booking (incluyendo admin) o incluso otro archivo me abre el archivo `db_conn.php` por lo que no puedo ver el panel de control donde se supone debo poner ese usuario y contraseña:

El contenido de `db_conn.php` es:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "db";

try {
    /*connect as appropriate as above*/
    $db=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);} catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo "Cannot connect to database";
    die();
}
?>
```

Originalmente venia con PDO pero yo lo cambié porque me daba error por alguna razón:

```
try {
    /*connect as appropriate as above*/
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Cannot connect to database";
    die();
}
?>
```

Si pongo un `echo` en el `try` sí lo muestra, por lo que sí se está realizando la conexión.

Comment: ¿Podrías copiar/pegar el código en el mensaje y no poner una captura de pantalla? ¿Podrías decir qué aplicación PHP estás usando y/o qué estás tratando de instalar o configurar? Eso nos ayudaría mucho. Por cierto, no puedes cambiar arbitrariamente la conexión de `mysqli` a `PDO` sin sufrir consecuencias en las zonas del código donde se realicen consultas ya que los métodos son muy diferentes.

Comment: estoy usando xampp, pero si la diferencia es tanta como dices de seguro el problema es lo del cambio que hice, lo que no se es por qué con mysqli si se conecta y con PDO no si son las mismas variables

Comment: No es que sean las mismas variables, el problema está en que las clases usadas son diferentes, las excepciones generadas también, los métodos para consultas preparadas son similares pero luego la asignación y obtención de datos son diferentes de nuevo, etc... mira el log de error del servidor xampp para ver si se están produciendo errores o advertencias dentro de tu página. De todos modos, ¿cómo "accedes a al carpeta de tu servidor"? ¿Estás usando una URL o desde el explorador de archivos?

Comment: Da la impresión de que tienes alguna redirección relativa a la subcarpeta `booking` a nivel de `.htaccess` por lo que cuando entras en esa sub-carpeta te envía a la URL donde está ese archivo.